# How to build a single-photon emitter at home

Tags: quantum-optics

Hey any of you people know if it's possible to make a DIY single-photon emitter? I've been searching for an answer for quite some time now and all I've come across that's helpful is this:

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-10917-3

Anyone have an alternate solution?
Thank you